# Align each block vertically in table-cell

Tags: html, css, block, vertical-alignment, tablecell

I have 1 parent table-cell `.t` and 2 child blocks `.ch1` and `.ch2`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="t">
    <div class="ch1">1</div>
    <div class="ch2">2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.t {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:green;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}

.ch1 {
    background-color:blue;
    display: block;
}

.ch2 {
    background-color:red;
    display: block;
}
```

Is it possible to push `.ch2` to bottom, but left `.ch1` on top (if use `vertical-align: bottom;` of `.t` it will push both blocks to bottom)

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hvz4cn69/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.t {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.ch1 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
.ch2 {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <div class="ch1">1</div>
  <div class="ch2">2</div>
</div>
```

Or

```css
.t {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.ch1 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
.ch2 {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <div class="ch1">1</div>
  <div class="ch2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, and is answer to question. But replacing table-cell to flex   makes some difference (actually I have more complex situation, but I simplified it in question to make it clearer https://jsfiddle.net/hvz4cn69/1/). Problem is flex itself fits in minimal height, and table-cell takes height of maximum table-cell in table: http://snag.gy/z9xql.jpg  . In result I want http://snag.gy/vV14L.jpg

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly it, seems flex is very powerful thing, I need to learn all about it

Comment: Indeed, flexbox is *awesome*.

Answer (score -1):

You may use `margin-top: 164px;` for `ch2`