# How to place the same image at the top and at the bottom of the same column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So the title pretty much explains my problem. For now, I have my image placed at the top of the column and at the same time I need it to be  at the bottom. How can I do this?

[image]

[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/eJLjZL)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 first-column"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 back-to-blog">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-neu-d1-6d077751650ba9cb23f065b16e4d4581/views/imgpsh_fullsize">
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  padding: 0 35px;
}

.first-column {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Just answered on just like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221068/align-each-block-vertically-in-table-cell but I'll add an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 35px;
}
.row {
  display: flex; /* columns now equal height */
}
.first-column {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 10; /* replicates md-10 */
}
.back-to-blog {
  flex: 2; /* replicates md-2 */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* sets directionality */
  justify-content: space-between; /* separates elements across direction */
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 first-column"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 back-to-blog">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-25-25-3.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-25-25-3.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That thing is legit. Do you know good info about the flexbox? I wanna learn it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way if you want to stick into Bootstrap column classes:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-10 col-md-10 first-column">aaa</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 back-to-blog">
      <a href="/"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-neu-d1-6d077751650ba9cb23f065b16e4d4581/views/imgpsh_fullsize"></a>
      <a href="/" class="btm-link"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-neu-d1-6d077751650ba9cb23f065b16e4d4581/views/imgpsh_fullsize"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  padding: 0 35px;
}

.first-column {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
}
.back-to-blog{
  height: 200px;
}
.btm-link{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZyGoQ

Comment: Yes, but please note that this requires you to *know* the height of the column...which you may not.

Comment: @Paulie_D You're correct. This solution might work out for static column height but if it's dynamic it will do more harm than good.